# Save image in SQLite database getting from the webservice

Tags: android, parsing, android-sqlite

I'm working on android app in which i parse the data from the webservice and then store it in the database. here i also want to store the image in the database and retrive back in the next activity.

I'm using this code for inserting the image in database.

```
Bitmap yourSelectedImage;
ByteArrayOutputStream stream;
byte[] byteArray;
```

this is in the  for loop

```
{ 
yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(SingleImageURL[i]);
stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
                    stream);
byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

database.insertDetail(ID[i],byteArray[i]); 

}
```

Here  SingleImageURL  have the image url that is coming from the webservice.

when i'm run the code it will give error nullPointerException in this line

```
 yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
                    stream);
```

please tell me where i'm going wrong. and how to do this.

Comment: debug your program and see what are you getting in SingleImageURL ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load your Bitmap `yourSelectedImage` using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android). and then save it to database by converting it to `byte[]`

You are decoding a file, which actually is a URL. So ur `yourSelectedImage` is `null`. And when you try to compress it using

```
yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

you get `NullPointerException`